# Webscrape the links on a webpage with JSOUP

Tags: java, api, web-scraping, jsoup

I'm using JSoup to scrape a webpage. Can anybody help me out or point me in the right direction for how to parse the text that is contained in this link. presently I'm running a for each loop and it will iterate through the elements but won't find the link and stops after 1 iteration.

the HTML..

```
<div>
  <div style = a bunch of different inline styles here>
    <div class = "_6d3hm _mnav9">
      <div class = "_mck9w _gvoze _tn0ps">
        <a href= "the link i want">_</a>
      </div>
      <div class = "_mck9w _gvoze _tn0ps">
        <a href= "another link i want">_</a>
      </div>
      <div class = "_mck9w _gvoze _tn0ps">
        <a href= "another link i want">_</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class = "_6d3hm _mnav9">
      <div class = "_mck9w _gvoze _tn0ps">
        <a href= "the link i want">_</a>
      </div>
      <div class = "_mck9w _gvoze _tn0ps">
        <a href= "another link i want">_</a>
      </div>
      <div class = "_mck9w _gvoze _tn0ps">
        <a href= "another link i want">_</a>
      </div>
```

This is my java using Soup. I've experimented with a bunch of different tags...

```
for (Element row : doc.select("div")) {
            System.out.println("iterating");
            final String link = row.getElementsByTag("._mck9w _gvoze _tn0ps").text();
            System.out.println(link);
        }
```

Does anybody have an idea how I can scrape every link i've mentioned in the HTML???

Comment: did any answer solve your problem? If so, please accept the appropriate answer and by that marking the question as solved for others. If you found an answer useful, don't hesitate to upvote for it.

Answer (score 2):

The error is in this line: `row.getElementsByTag("._mck9w _gvoze _tn0ps")`.
You are looking for tags `a` and its attribute `href`, so your code should look like this:

```
for (Element row : doc.select("div")) {
    System.out.println("iterating");
    final String link = row.getElementsByTag("a").attr("href");
    System.out.println(link);
}
```

If you want to use the fact, that div has class attribute with given values you can try something like this:

```
for(Element e: doc.select("div._mck9w._gvoze._tn0ps > a")) {
    System.out.println(e.attr("href"));
};
```

[jsop documentation](https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax)

[more about css selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)